# May I return to our marital home? separated two months

Tags: talaq

My husband of 25 years has decided he no longer loves me after I found him in a haram relationship with a younger woman and has made me leave our home. He has not mentioned divorce at all. I have nowhere else to go, so I have lived with my father and brother after then. It has been over two months, and I wish to return because it is my home. I have been paying my father for letting me stay at his home. My husband has not supported me during this time, so living at my father's has been very bad on my finances. I wish for reconciliation with my husband, but I fear he is unwilling.

Is it permissible for me to return home despite his objection? Or would it be sinful? I am sorry for the poor english it is not my first language.

Comment: As long as he has not divorced you you are still married and can go back.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If he does not let me go back within three months (maybe he change the locks), is it considered divorce? Even if he has not said talaq.

Comment: It is not considered divorce unless he gives divorce, no matter how long you remain separate.

Comment: Thank you! @UmH